# Read .xml file on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, xml-serialization

I add .xml file to my roject. Now I need to open it. I try FileStream, StreamReader, IsolatedStorageFileStream. But there are get exception in each case. Somebody know how can i open local xml file and get data from it?

```
    public static AllFlags Load()
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        AllFlags allFlags;

        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open);
        //StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filename);
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllFlags));
        allFlags = xml.Deserialize(stream) as AllFlags;
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();

        return allFlags;
    }
```

Comment: Typically you would use `XmlDocument` for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need xml specific information, but just read the contents of the file this is the easiest way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"drive:\path\to\your\file.xml");
```

Otherwise there are speficied xml objects in the framework to do so. Typically you would use `XmlDocument`. See the example below.

Obtained from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample {

  public static void Main() {

    // Create the XmlDocument.
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"drive:/path/to/you/file.xml");

    //Get data from the Xml File
    XmlNode Node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/apple/price");

   // Add a price element.
   XmlElement newElem = doc.CreateElement("price");
   newElem.InnerText = "10.95";
   doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem);

    // Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
    XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml",null);
    writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    doc.Save(writer);
  }
}
```

Also see this link as its a good tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument

Comment: This is not answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let say that you have created the folder XmlFiles in your WP8 project (at the root level). You can load the xml like this:

```
var doc = XElement.Load("XmlFiles/NameOfXmlFile.xml");
```

Notice that there are no leading `..` or `/` characters. Also, check the properties of the xml file. The Build Action must be set to `Content` and the Copy to Output Directory should be `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.